# PHPSpreadsheet reading spreadsheet as a stream

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm pulling a spreadsheet from an FTP directory and I need to read it with PHPSpreadsheet. I can read a local file just fine, but not sure how to do it when I'm getting a stream of data.

Is this even possible? I'm not finding much in documentation support for it.

Not including code since I don't believe it is needed for the question.

Much thanks!

Comment: Save it locally (on the server or your machine) then process it. If necessary use the PHP functions to generate a temporary file name in the temp directory then unlink the file when you're done with it.

Comment: Strangely enough this question doesn't seem to interrest much people. I am facing the same situation and cannot find any resource detailing the possibility to load from a stream / raw data. So far I haven't found a better way than save data to a temporary file and then load it using `IOFactory::createReader()->load()`. Any comment on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I take the example of an XLSX file, it cannot be streamed because it needs to be inflated first ; you may rename any .xlsx into .zip, it will basically work.

If you only want to process XLSX files, you may unzip them from PHP, and then stream any XML file contained in the inflated `worksheets` directory using the [xml parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) for example. Rows are avilable at xpath `/worksheet/sheetData/row` and values are available at xpath `/worksheet/sheetData/row/c/v`.

You'll probably need an implementation for each and every types of files you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```php
<?php
// FTP connection settings
$ftpServer = 'ftp.example.com';
$ftpUsername = 'your-username';
$ftpPassword = 'your-password';

// FTP file path
$ftpFilePath = '/path/to/spreadsheet.xlsx';

// Local temporary file path
$tempFilePath = '/path/to/temporary/file.xlsx';

// Connect to FTP server
$ftpConnection = ftp_connect($ftpServer);
ftp_login($ftpConnection, $ftpUsername, $ftpPassword);

// Download file from FTP directory
if (ftp_get($ftpConnection, $tempFilePath, $ftpFilePath, FTP_BINARY)) {
    // Open stream from local file
    $stream = fopen($tempFilePath, 'r');

    // Load spreadsheet using PHPSpreadsheet
    $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($stream);

    // Close the stream
    fclose($stream);

    // Process the spreadsheet data as needed
    // ...

    // Delete the temporary file
    unlink($tempFilePath);
} else {
    echo "Failed to download file from FTP directory.";
}

// Close FTP connection
ftp_close($ftpConnection);
?>
```